# Wordpress Plugin with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, plugins

I am working on a wordpress plugin which allows a user to enter a image url and [konami code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Konami_Code). When the konami code is entered an image pops up, but I can't get it to animate, I am somewhat unfamiliar with jQuery and Javascript, and I am just starting to learn it... Any help would be fantastic!

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
if ( window.addEventListener ) {
  var kkeys = [], konami = "{$this->opts['wpk_code']['current']}";
  window.addEventListener("keydown", function(e){
    kkeys.push( e.keyCode );
    if ( kkeys.toString().indexOf( konami ) >= 0 ){
     var elms=document.getElementById("konami").style;
     elms.display=(elms.display=="block")?"none":"block";
}
  }, true);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a play with some of the examples on jQuery's [animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) - they seem to do what you want.

Comment: Yes, I have tried several different ways of adding that function - however if i remove 'var elms=document.getElementById("konami").style;
     elms.display=(elms.display=="block")?"none":"block";' which tells the display to switch from none to block - the image doesnt appear, and when I add to the code it doesn't animate.

Comment: I see - depending on your animation you can call .show() or do something like $('#konami').animate({ 'opacity': 'show' }, 1000 );

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#inputField').keyup(function () {
            if ($(this).val().length > 0) {
                $('#konami').animate({
                    opacity: 1,
                    left: '50'
                }, 100); 
            }
            else {
                $('#konami').animate({
                    opacity: 0,
                    left: '0'
                }, 100); 
            }
        });
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="inputField" />
<img src="..." id="konami" style="position:relative;" />
```

Comment: that just adds an input box and hides the image... When a specific code is executed by the user an image should pops up -which it does, but I want to add animate so it slides across the page.

Comment: Then you should take a look at the animate method in jquery. you can find it here: http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Comment: Look above i have add some new lines of code that will move the image 50px and fade. NOTE that the new style property on the img - style="position:relative;" is critical.

Comment: thanks! I got it..`<script>
var kkeys = [];
var konami = "{$this->opts['wpk_code']['current']}";
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
    kkeys.push(e.keyCode);
    if (kkeys.toString().indexOf(konami) >= 0)
    {
        kkeys = [];
        $(".konami").show(1000);
    }
});
</script>`
`<div class="konami" style="display: none">
    <p class="konami2">
        <img src="<?php echo $url?>" />
    </p>
</div>`

Comment: Great :) If you found my answer´s useful, feel free to mark it :)